# Programmatically get menu block & alter classes

Tags: 7, blocks

I'm invoking a menu block programmatically using:
    module_invoke('menu_block', 'block_view', 13);

What I want to do is change and add classes to the wrapper & ul tags of the menu block, is this possible? I can't seem to find a class_array to add  & have spent a significant amount of time looking through documentation & online but not come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

borrowed from [here:](https://www.drupal.org/node/2295461)

add the following code in your template.php file.

```
<?php
  function THEME_menu_tree__main_menu($variables) {
    return '<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
  }
?>
```

this would update the `<ul>` for main menu, adjust as necessary. You can adjust further up the chain within the [page.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!page.tpl.php/7) file.